# "Under the condition that" within the realm of probaility

Tags: mathematics

SO, I have a math question, kind of at least, where I think the wording is getting in the way.

> Determine the probability that *First condition* under the condition that *Second condition*.

I understand this as the first condition, only when the second condition.  However, others have seen this as First condition and second condition.  What is the proper understanding of the phase "under the condition that", and can it ever be used as a form of and?

Comment: are you sure about the italics? As is I cannot parse this sentence, it does not seem to make any sense, it lacks a verb.

Comment: @P.Obertelli I did not want to put the full phrase because it may look too much like I was asking for homework help, and the conditions sections are just placeholder phrases.  Should I put them back in?

Comment: @P.Obertelli That parses to "Determine the probability that *First condition* **is true** under the condition that *Second condition* **is true**.

Comment: In Probabilistics it would be p(A|B), where A is First condition and B is Second condition. It's [conditional probability.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) It isn't p(A^B) because you know B is true.

Comment: @Yay I was thinking it was that.  Thanks for the confirmation.  If you put that as an answer, I will pick that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematical English, rather than normal idiomatic natural English as spoken by human beings ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In probability it would be p(A|B), where A is *First condition* and B is *Second condition*. It's [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), not a conjunction p(A^B), because "under the condition that *Second condition"* is already telling you B is true.

**What is the proper understanding of the phrase "under the condition that"?**

Well, the expression itself is pretty much self-explanatory. "A under the condition that B", "A given B" or "A if B is true" all mean A|B.

**Can it ever be used as a form of "and"?**

Strictly speaking, no it can't. However, that doesn't mean they cannot be *mathematically* equivalent. If p(B)=1, then p(A|B)=p(A^B). Logically speaking though, they are different things.

Comment: "Probabilistics" is not a word, but the rest of the answer is correct.